# Send an email with two attachment, each one with a different encoding

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I want to send an email with ActionMailer. I want to send the same csv encoding in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8

My Mailer :

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "Me <contact@me.com>"

  # ===========
  # = Reports =
  # ===========

  # report is in UTF-8
  def send_report(email, report, subject, filename, campaign_id)
    attachments[filename + '.utf_8.csv']= { :data => report, :encoding => 'base64',  :mime_type => "text/csv" }
    attachments[filename + '.latin1.csv']= { :data => report.encode('ISO-8859-1'), :encoding => 'base64', :mime_type => "text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1" }

    @campaign_id = campaign_id
    mail(to: email, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

And I got the error :

```
incompatible character encodings: ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8
```

If I try to send each of them individually, it works fine...

Comment: Try changing it to: `.force_encoding("iso-8859-1")`

Comment: For a cheap and dirty fix, you could archive the two CSVs and send it that way.

Comment: It does not work @fmendez

Answer (score 0):

ActionMailer docs stipulate that

> If you want to use a different encoding than Base64, you can pass an encoding in, but then it is up to you to pass in the content pre-encoded

So it looks like you want to double-encode your attachment. I would first remove the :encoding options. Second, you don't show us where the encoding error is occurring. Maybe you have UTF-8 in your document that cannot be encoded as ISO?

Third, you pass `report` into the attachment hash. It might be that something calls `force_encoding` on it. However, since Ruby is pass-by-reference, this would also affect your second attachment.

Fail that, and I would try switching the mime type to `application/octetstream`

And lastly I'd dive into the AM source. Also I would send a ray of burning hate to people having ISO-encoded files as a requirement.